# How to refresh Repeater and SqlDataSource c# or vb.net

Tags: c#, jquery, vb.net, repeater, sqldatasource

In My application i am using Repeater and binding data using SqlDataSource 
and in that i am performing add operation after that i want Repeater should be refreshed inorder to show newly added record

Code i used:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptOrderReport" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" DataSourceID="OrderReportDataSource">
            <HeaderTemplate><tr><td>        
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" rules="all" class="reports"  align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;" >Order Report</td>
                </tr>

  <tr class="rptHeadr">
                        <td>SKU</td>
                        <td>Color</td>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>To Order Total</td>
                    </tr></HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr <%--class="rptRow"--%>>
                        <td><%# Eval("ItemSKU")%></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("ColorName")%></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("ItemSize")%></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("TotalCount")%></td>
                    </tr></ItemTemplate> 
                   <FooterTemplate></table></td></tr></FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Sql DataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource  EnableViewState="false" ID="OrderReportDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbWRConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand= "Exec [spGetOrderReport] @OrderId">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="OrderID" DbType="String" QueryStringField="OID"/>
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and i made a button to open a popup to add new values and in popup close i wrote page Refresh inorder to show repeater with new data.

Code: on popup close

```
$('.popCloseAddcolor').click(function () {         
                location.reload(); 
            $('.popHolderAddColor').hide();
            $('.popHolderSkuEdit').css("display", "none");
            $('.popCloseSkuEdit').hide();
        });
```

But its not good thing to refresh page, is there any other way to Refresh only repeater through Jquery/Back end event fire..

Comment: Do you use the AjaxControlToolkit?

Comment: No i didnt used that

Answer (score 0):

```
        protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OrderReportDataSource.SelectCommand = "Exec [spGetOrderReport] " + Request.QueryString["OrderId"];
            OrderReportDataSource.DataBind();

        }
```

### Call Button click event using javascript use below code:

```
                  document.getElementById("btnClick").click();
```

Hope it helps...